# Spring Integration Http+amqp rabbitmq-Concurrency issues for 100 users

Tags: spring, http, spring-rabbit

Im using spring Http Integration and amqp for rabbit mq,its failing in
    loadtesting for concurrent users...
    Message counts which showing in jmeter and rabbitmq message counts are not
    matching..its working fine  for till 30 users

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway id="logIngesterGatewayBulk"
        supported-methods="POST" request-channel="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk"
        path="/rest/log/bulk" error-channel="errorChannel" reply-timeout="10" 
        request-payload-type="java.lang.String">
    </int-http:inbound-gateway>

<int:filter input-channel="logIngesterRestEndpointBulk"
        throw-exception-on-rejection="true" method="validate" ref="payloadValidation"
        output-channel="filterChannelbulk">
    </int:filter>

     <int:chain input-channel="filterChannelbulk" output-channel="messageOutputChannel" id="chaining" >
        <int:splitter id="splitter" ref="payloadSplitter" method="splitPayLoad" >

        </int:splitter>
        <int:transformer id="logMessageTransformerbulk" ref="logMessageHeaderTransformer"
            method="transform">
        </int:transformer>
    </int:chain>
    <int:service-activator input-channel="errorChannel"
        ref="responseHandler" method="handleFailedPayLoad">
    </int:service-activator>


<int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter  
        id="amqpAdapter" channel="messageOutputChannel" amqp-template="amqpTemplate" 
        exchange-name="dhp_exchange" routing-key-expression="headers['routingKey']">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out why there are mismatches. Debugging 101, I'm afraid.

Start with figuring out which messages are lost, and why - DEBUG logging will help but it can be tedious to trace through the logs to follow each message, but the information is definitely in there. Be sure to include the thread name in your log configuration; it's mandatory when debugging multi-threaded applications.

You need to ensure your code is thread-safe - `payloadValidation`, `payloadSplitter`, `logMessageHeaderTransformer` beans etc - no shared state (fields) or synchronization is correct.

Comment: Hey, its solved by using <task:executor id="bulkChannelExecutor"      
   />

Comment: its now able to recieve 100 concurrent user requests...thanks